# Is there a way to tile a background image over a canvas path?

Tags: javascript, dom, drawing, canvas, excanvas

For example, I have a canvas in a page with some kind of a path. It is created by javascript this way:

```
var context = $('#some_canvas').getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(100, 100);
context.stroke();
```

Is there a way to make the path that appears after this command to have some tiled background image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [createPattern()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#Patterns) method:

```
var pattern = new Image;
pattern.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
pattern.onload = function () {
    var context = $('#some_canvas').getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 16;
    context.strokeStyle = context.createPattern(pattern, 'repeat');
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(150, 150);
    context.stroke();
};
```